# Next and Previous Navigation by showing corresponding DIV

Tags: javascript, html, navigation

I am in the lookout for a script that can show one DIV at a time and Hide the rest (2 in the example I took)additionally I want the user to navigate back and forth

i.e

Once the user clicks next DIV 1 is displayed so on till DIV3 
He should also be able to traverse from DIV2 - DIV1 and so on

I did find this development interesting

http://jsfiddle.net/meetrk85/Y7mfF/

Thanks a billion in advance.....

Comment: Maybe [tag:html] instead of [tag:displaying]? `:P`

Comment: "I am in the lookout for a script"... are you looking for help on how to write a script, or be provided one?

Comment: How 'interesting' did you find it? Enough to make a start on a script? Because that linked JS Fiddle has `</div>`s trying to close `a` elements, and `value` attributes on the `a` elements (which seems to be invalid [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/a). So, [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) And where are you stuck?

Comment: I am stuck with the PREV navigation this is another script that i came across http://jsfiddle.net/meetrk85/EuDHN/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="sample">div1</div>
<div class="sample">div2</div>
<div class="sample">div3</div>
<a href="#" id="display" class="display">next</a>
<a href="#" id="display1" class="display">prev</a>
```

The following jQuery seems to achieve your requirements:

```
// selects all the divs of class='sample',hides them, finds the first, and shows it
$('div.sample').hide().first().show();

// binds a click event-handler to a elements whose class='display'
$('a.display').on('click', function(e) {
    // prevents the default action of the link
    e.preventDefault();

    // assigns the currently visible div.sample element to a variable
    var that = $('div.sample:visible'),
        // assigns the text of the clicked-link to a variable for comparison purposes
        t = $(this).text();

    // checks if it was the 'next' link, and ensures there's a div to show after the currently-shown one
    if (t == 'next' && that.next('div.sample').length > 0) {
        // hides all the div.sample elements
        $('div.sample').hide();

        // shows the 'next'
        that.next('div.sample').show()
    }
    // exactly the same as above, but checking that it's the 'prev' link
    // and that there's a div 'before' the currently-shown element.
    else if (t == 'prev' && that.prev('div.sample').length > 0) {
        $('div.sample').hide();
        that.hide().prev('div.sample').show()
    }
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Y7mfF/10/).

References:

- [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

---

### Addenda:

A quick explanation of why I changed the [html in the linked demo](http://jsfiddle.net/meetrk85/Y7mfF/):

```
<div name="sample">div1</div>
<div name="sample">div2</div>
<div name="sample">div3</div>
<a href="#" id="display" value="display">next</div>
<a href="#" id="display1" value="display">prev</div>
```

- The `name` attribute, in a `div` serves no purpose. Certainly not if all the elements are sharing the same name (they're not `input` elements, they're linked-to by an `a`, so use a `class` name).
- The value attribute has no [association with an `a` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html), and serves, so far as I can tell, no purpose. For this, in the script above, I chose, again, to use a `class` name, since the same 'value' of the attribute was shared, though a `data-*` attribute could have been used, and would have been valid.
- The closing `</div>` tags weren't closing anything, so they were changed to `</a>`.

Comment: Let me first tell this works like magic wow thanks a billion David for your time :)

Comment: You're welcome; though I'd really suggest you start learning HTML, and JavaScript.